# Javax validation of generics in Springboot with Kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, kotlin, generics

I have a controller:

```
@PostMapping
fun create(
  @RequestBody @Valid request: MyContainer<CreateRequest>,
): MyContainer<Dto> = service.create(request.objects)
```

with MyContainer and CreateRequest looking something like this:

```
class MyContainer<T>(
  @field:Valid // also tried param
  @field:NotEmpty(message = "The list of objects can not be null or empty")
  var objects: List<@Valid T>? = listOf(),
)
```

```
class CreateRequest(
  @field:NotNull(message = "Value can not be null")
  var value: BigDecimal? = null,
)
```

In my tests, the "outer" validation works, that is I do get the expected error message if I send it `{ "objects": null }` or `{ "objects": [] }`. But I can not get it to validate the contents of the list. From what I understand in Java `List<@Valid T>` should work, but for whatever I can not get it to work in kotlin.

I figured I might need some kind of use-site target on `@Valid` in `List<@Valid T>`, but I can't find one that's applicable for this use case.

How can I get the validation to work for the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution myself.

Apparently `get:` is the correct use-site target, not `field:` or `param:`. Furthermore the `@Valid` in `List<@Valid T>` was not necessary.

For reference, here's the working class (also changed it back to a data class as that doesn't seem to pose an issue).

```
class MyContainer<T>(
  @get:Valid
  @get:NotEmpty(message = "The list of objects can not be null or empty")
  var objects: List<T>? = listOf(),
)
```

and the CreateRequest:

```
class CreateRequest(
  @get:NotNull(message = "Value can not be null")
  var value: BigDecimal? = null,
)
```

Changing to the `get:` use-site target was only necessary for `@Valid`, but I opted for using it everywhere for consistency and since it seems to be the one that works best.